# Validate username and password without authenticating the user

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

Using Asp.Net Identity 2.x with WebApi 2.x (both latest), is it possible to just validate a given username and password in order to know if the provided information is valid, without actually authenticating the user?

I am working on a partial login in our identity service and it's essential that I don't authenticate the user till the approval of EULA licanse agreement after providing the valid credentials. That is where I'am struggling...

Sorry for not providing any code, I hope the problem is obvious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have created/defined a `UserManager` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) in your project you can try to find your user by his/her username and, if found, call `VerifyHashedPassword` method using the `PasswordHasher` member.

```
string userName = "my-user-name";
string password = "my-password";

var user = await ApplicationUserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
if (user != null)
{
    PasswordVerificationResult result = ApplicationUserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, password);
}
```

It returns a `PasswordVerificationResult`: **Failed**, **Success**, **SuccessRehashNeeded**.

NOTES:

`ApplicationUserManager` is my implementation of [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Right to the boolseye :)